# C++ Makefile doesn't compile dependencies/ linking error?

Tags: c++, makefile

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question.
I'm new to Makefiles in C++ and I just wrote a simple one like so:

```
game: game.o state.o move.o board.o
    g++ state.o move.o board.o game.o -o game

game.o: game.cpp
    g++ -c game.cpp

state.o: state.cpp state.h
    g++ -c state.cpp

move.o: move.cpp move.h
    g++ -c move.cpp

board.o: board.cpp board.h
    g++ -c board.cpp

clean: 
    rm *.o game
```

When I run "make game", all functions called in game.cpp which are defined in state.cpp generate an error, and state.cpp includes move.h and board.h. Basically, it's as if I'm only running "g++ -c game.c".

I don't really understand how to fix this. Should I be changing the order of the dependencies?

Thank you!

Comment: If you `make clean` and then run `make game`, what command does `make` show you? And what error do you get? Can you please copy-paste the full and complete output of that into the question?

Comment: Oh by the way, `clean` hardly depends on `rm`, `*.o` and `game`. You miss a newline after `clean:`.

Comment: Your Makefile looks very strange. Normally those are represented by variables, not hardcoded. And header dependency can also be generated by compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, fixed the `clean` command

Comment: The output is something like this:  `g++    game.C  -o game`
   `undefined reference to State::setSize(int)'`
   `undefined reference to State::setToMove(int)'`
   `undefined reference to State::setToMove(int)'` ...it goes through all my State class functions not recognizing any of them

Comment: That command you show in your comment (which should really be in your question) doesn't match any in the `Makefile` you show us. There's no `game.C`. The command doesn't have any `-c` argument. Are you using the correct `Makefile`?

Comment: So your game.cpp includes none of your headers directly or indirectly, state.cpp only includes state.h, move.cpp only includes move.h, and board.cpp only includes board.h. I wonder how you are able to combine this set of files that have nothing to do with each other into a coherent program.

Comment: @ellen assuming that the output you just pasted in is actually what you're getting, notices that the file being compiled first is `game.C` and not `game.cpp`, so it would not match any (explicit) rules in your makefile.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @Turix Sorry! :/ I went back to edit the comment and I'm using .C extensions in another project so... that's just a typo in the comment. I meant to write `g++ game.cpp -o game`...

Comment: It doesn't make that much difference, since the `-c` option you have in the `Makefile` you show still is missing (and you have an `-o` option that isn't in the `Makefile` you're showing). The `Makefile` you show is not the same as the one you're using.

Comment: try changing the order, so that `state.o` goes after `game.o`

Comment: Is the error message a secret?

Comment: @liliscent: It's not "strange", though would want increased automation for productisation, that is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the actual error is this:

```
 g++ game.C -o game
 undefined reference to State::setSize(int)' undefined reference to State::setToMove(int)' undefined reference to State::setToMove(int)'
```

I would say that you do not have a `game.cpp` source file, but a `game.C` source file, and an implicit make rule kicks in to build `game`.  See:

- [Catalogue of Built-in Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html)

You can run make with the `--no-builtin-rules` option to disable them.